# IPad WebApp Rendering CSS Differently Than Chrome

Tags: css, ipad, web-applications, meta, iphone-standalone-web-app

Surprisingly (at least to me), when I use the ipad emulator in Chrome, I see a very different layout than when I launch my iPad webapp:
- in chrome : [screenshot of chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU9qC.png)
- on my ipad : [screnshot of ipad version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MdMA.png)

The background resolution is 2732x2048.

- images and fonts absolutely don't have the same size
- the bottom selectors, which are absoluted position with bottom:0 won't end up at the same location
- a few background lines are missing on the bottom part of the ipad version

the page html is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<style>
    body {position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        background-image: url('images/rl-background-grid.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;}
    .navigation {bottom: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
This is a test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find the actual page here :

```
http://rl.manuelracim.com/test/test.html
```

Am I missing something obvious in my header? Or is it a problem that all my CSS rules are expressed in px?
Any pointer/help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools ipad "emulator" just spoofs the user-agent and sizes the viewport - it's in no way meant to be a realistic way to emulate an ipad. If you have a Mac computer, the xCode emulator is a much wiser choice - nothing beats testing on a real device though.

Comment: Thanks, that's why I used the real device and realized there were big differences; I'm coding under windows. Any idea what I should look at to fix this layout?

Comment: you'll need to update your question to give a minimum viable example to replicate the issue - basically posting all the necessary code etc - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask